# How to call a stored procedure from a function

Tags: sql, pervasive-sql

I want to call a stored procedure from a user defined function in pervasive sql. I have:

```
SET :retVal = Sales_SP_getNetSales('2013-1-1','2013-1-31','05',:NetSales);
```

as a call in my function where Sales_SP_getNetSales is the stored procedure. Is this the correct way of doing it? The stored procedure returns an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any way to call a Stored Procedure from a UDF. Running a Stored Procedure requires either the EXEC(UTE) or CALL statement.  There is, however, no way to translate the result set returned by the Stored Procedure to a variable in a Pervasive UDF. Part of this may be because a Stored Procedure cannot be guaranteed to return only one value. A Stored Procedure, in Pervasive, returns a whole result set.
You might consider changing the Stored Procedure to a Function.  Calling a function from a function is possible:

```
create function f2(:B integer)
returns integer
as  
begin
return :B;
end;

CREATE FUNCTION f1(:A integer)
RETURNS Integer
AS
BEGIN 
RETURN f2(:a);
END;

select f1(5)
```

Comment: well explain differences between Procedure and Function, now I know.